# Is there any way to skip the escaped quote inside the double quoted TextMate rule

Tags: syntax-highlighting, textmate

I'm writing my custom language using the TextMate highlight syntax.
This is my rule to detect the double quoted string.

```
   "str_double_quote": {
        "begin" : "\"",
        "end" : "\"",
        "name": "string.quoted.double.skill"
   }
```

This rule works well for the normal cases, but for the case the string contains the escaped double quote like this:

```
"This is my \"test\" string"
```

The highlight is not correct. See my picture for detail[image]

I tried to look at the implementation for python and java. I see the highlight rule is same as mine but it's worked. Can you help to correct my rule?

Comment: Can you use a negative look-behind to test if the quote is (not) preceded by a backslash? Something like this: `"end" : "(?<!\\)\""`?

Comment: I already tried this approach. It seems TextMate doesn't support negative look-behind in the regex.

Comment: Right, what about something like `"end": "[^\\]""`?

Comment: It doesn't work. But so funny. I tried this regex: "end" : ".*\"" and it's worked. I don't know what was happen

Comment: Oh no, it's doesn't work well. all the position args was recognized as one string when using the `"end" : ".*\"" `
Ex:  `func("first" var_1 "other_string") `

Answer (score 0):

You can match an escaped double quote mark (`\"`) and a literal backslash (`\\`) in the patterns to consume them before the end marker is used to handle them:

```
    "str_double_quote": {
        "begin": "\"",
        "end": "\"",
        "name": "string.quoted.double.skill",
        "patterns": [
            {
                "name": "constant.character.escape.skill",
                "match": "\\\\[\"\\\\]"
            }
        ]
    }
```

This works fine for me in Visual Studio Code.

What I initially struggled with was that there are two levels of escaping, for the JSON encoding as well as the regular expression syntax. To match `\"`, the regular expression requires you to escape the backslash (`\\"`). JSON requires you to escape backslashes and double quotes, resulting in `\\\\\"` in a TextMate JSON grammar file.